# I'm attempting to add an if statement which checks whether the input is a string with python3, returns an error when passing an argument anyway

Tags: python, syntax-error, python-3.7

I'm a beginner learning how to code. I've written the following code because I'm attempting to learn how to handle a problem if the input is a string instead of a number.

Currently running Python3.7.3, I tried to use `.isalpha()`. 
I first tried `if numOfGuests.isalpha:` and `numOfGuests == str(numOfGuests)` but those didn't work either. intellisense tells me that there is a syntax error on line 8 with `if` underlined. Why? I'm still learning so I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong

```
name = ''

while not name:
    print('Enter your name ')
    name = input()
print ('How many guests will you have')
numOfGuests = input()
if numOfGuests == str(numOfGuests)
    print('those are letters, not numbers')
    else:
      pass
if numOfGuests == int()
    print('Be sure that you have enough room for all your guests')
print('Done')
```

I expected the system to just print 'those are letters, not numbers' and then start over from 'how many guests will you have'

error message:

```
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
PS C:\Users\name\Desktop\python> cd 'c:\Users\name\Desktop\python'; ${env:PYTHONIOENCODING}='UTF-8'; ${env:PYTHONUNBUFFERED}='1'; & 'C:\Python\Python37\python.exe' 'c:\Users\name\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2019.6.22090\pythonFiles\ptvsd_launcher.py' '--default' '--client' '--host' 'localhost' '--port' 'omitted for security' 'c:\Users\name\Desktop\python\truthy and falsey.py' Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\name\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2019.6.22090\pythonFiles\ptvsd_launcher.py", line 43, in <module>
    main(ptvsdArgs)
  File "c:\Users\name\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2019.6.22090\pythonFiles\lib\python\ptvsd\__main__.py", line 434, in main
    run()
  File "c:\Users\name\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2019.6.22090\pythonFiles\lib\python\ptvsd\__main__.py", line 312, in run_file
    runpy.run_path(target, run_name='__main__')
  File "C:\Python\Python37\lib\runpy.py", line 261, in run_path
    code, fname = _get_code_from_file(run_name, path_name)
  File "C:\Python\Python37\lib\runpy.py", line 236, in _get_code_from_file
    code = compile(f.read(), fname, 'exec')
  File "c:\Users\name\Desktop\python\truthy and falsey.py", line 8
    if numOfGuests == str(numOfGuests)
                                     ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: You're missing a colon. Or in `if numOfGuests.isalpha:`, parentheses. Please learn the basic language syntax. Then note `numOfGuests == int()` will *never* be true, because `numOfGuests` is a string an `int()` is an `int` (`0`).

Comment: Also `else` must be on the same indentation level as `if`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In addition to the other issues raised in the comments, you're assuming that testing using types like `str()` and `int()` will tell you what's in a string variable.  That's not a valid idea.  Here is the most direct version of you code I could come up with that does what I think you want:

```
name = ''

while not name:
    print('Enter your name ')
    name = input()
print ('How many guests will you have')
numOfGuests = input()
if not numOfGuests.isdecimal():
    print('those are letters, not numbers')
else:
    print('Be sure that you have enough room for all your guests')
print('Done')
```

There's a lot more that could be improved here, but I'm thinking that getting you going with something that actually runs will help you to continue along your learning path.  For example, there are better ways of checking for valid numeric input.

Comment: You're at the start of a wonderful journey.  Being able to program is an amazing thing.  I've been doing it for over 40 years (since I was 14), and I still love it and am still often amazed at what I can do.  Best of luck!